# Regex to find iframe tags and retrieve attributes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to retrieve `iframe` tags and attributes from an HTML input.

**Sample input**

```
<div class="1"><iframe width="100%" height="427px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
<div class="2"><iframe width="100%" height="427px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
```

I have been trying to collect them using the following regex:

```
<iframe.+?width=[\"'](?<width>.*?)[\"']?height=[\"'](?<height>.*?)[\"']?src=[\"'](?<src>.*?)[\"'].+?>
```

This results in

[image]

This is exactly the format I want.

The problem is, if the HTML attributes are in a different order this regex won't work.

Is there any way to modify this regex to ignore the attribute order and return the `iframe`s grouped in `Matches` so that I could iterate through them?

Comment: id not parse html with regex... have you tried using html agility pack?

Comment: alternative you could try to parse it as xml using linq2xml ... depends on how well formed it is

Comment: regex is a powerful tool, no doubt about it, but it strongly depends on the appliance. for xml or html there are tools that will allow you to write much more readable code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex that will ignore the order of attributes:

```
(?<=<iframe[^>]*?)(?:\s*width=["'](?<width>[^"']+)["']|\s*height=["'](?<height>[^'"]+)["']|\s*src=["'](?<src>[^'"]+["']))+[^>]*?>
```

[RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%3Ciframe%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3F)(%3F%3A%5Cs*width%3D%5B%22%27%5D(%3F%3Cwidth%3E%5B%5E%22%27%5D%2B)%5B%22%27%5D%7C%5Cs*height%3D%5B%22%27%5D(%3F%3Cheight%3E%5B%5E%27%22%5D%2B)%5B%22%27%5D%7C%5Cs*src%3D%5B%22%27%5D(%3F%3Csrc%3E%5B%5E%27%22%5D%2B%5B%22%27%5D))%2B%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3F%3E&i=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%221%22%3E%3Ciframe%20%0D%0Awidth%3D%22100%25%22%0D%0Aheight%3D%22427px%22%20%0D%0Asrc%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F1%22%0D%0Aframeborder%3D%220%22%0D%0Aallowfullscreen%3D%22%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%222%22%3E%3Ciframe%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22427px%22%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F2%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E)

C# sample code:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=<iframe[^>]*?)(?:\s*width=[""'](?<width>[^""']+)[""']|\s*height=[""'](?<height>[^'""]+)[""']|\s*src=[""'](?<src>[^'""]+[""']))+[^>]*?>");
var input = @"YOUR INPUT STRING";
var matches = rx.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions match patterns, and the structure of your string defines which pattern to use, thus, if you want to use regular expressions order is important.

You can deal with this in 2 ways:

1. The **good and recommended** way is to **not** parse HTML with regular expressions ([mandatory link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)), but rather use a parsing framework such as the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This should allow you to process the HTML you need and extract any values you are after.
2. The 2nd, **bad, and non recommended way** to do this is to break your matching into 2 parts. You first use something like so: `<iframe(.+?)></iframe>` to extract the *entire* iframe decleration and then, use multiple, smaller regular expressions to seek out and find the settings you are after. The above regex obviously fails if your iframe is structured like so: `<iframe.../>`. This should give you a hint as to *why* you should not do HTMl parsing through regular expressions.

As stated, you should go with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an OR operator (|).  See changes below

```
<iframe.+?width=[\"']((?<width>.*?)[\"']?)|(height=[\"'](?<height>.*?)[\"']?)|(src=[\"'](?<src>.*?)[\"']))*.+?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
<iframe[ ]+(([a-z]+) *= *['"]*([a-zA-Z0-9\/:\.%]*)['"]*[ ]*)*>
```

it matches each 'name'='value' pair recursively and stores it in the same order in matches, you can iterate through the mathes to get names and values sequentially. Caters for most chars in value but you may add a few more if needed.

Answer (score 1):

With Html Agility Pack (to be had via nuget):

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load("HTMLPage1.html"); //or .LoadHtml(/*contentstring*/);

            HtmlNodeCollection iframes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe");

            foreach (HtmlNode iframe in iframes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iframe.GetAttributeValue("width","null"));
                Console.WriteLine(iframe.GetAttributeValue("height", "null"));
                Console.WriteLine(iframe.GetAttributeValue("src","null"));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was thinking it could be done with this, but regex is preferred.